# preventing booting from USB

Tags: bios

Some students where I work think it's very funny to hack into the system. 
One of the methods they use is to connect a USB-stick wich they installed linux on it, boot from the USB-stick, and play around with some files. 
I tryied blocking the option through the BIOS but coudn't find the option. 
the BIOS installed on the mechines is from Award Software. (didn't manage to find any version or something). 
Does any one know what to do? 
**edit:** I managed to put a password on the BIOS (this way when you enter the setup menu you requested to enter a password in order to change something) but this doesn't prevent me from choosing a temporary boot device.

Comment: look in the bios more. take a picture of the bios with  a digital camera or smartphone, and upload the picture here and maybe some here can show you where the option is. you can change the boot order and disable booting from usb, and hopefully lock  entering the bios with a password.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the make/model of your PC or motherboard in your question

Comment: @Tog better to keep it more generic. Like "include the model of motherboard so we can find the manual and look at the BIOS pages in the manual" (assuming that's your plan). Though he said it's award BIOS. So he probably has to choose something like BIOS features. Just look on google images for what the award bios looks like

Comment: @elyashiv - Just set BIOS not to boot from a USB device.

Answer (score 1):

Use a BIOS password to protect the BIOS